# Variable for Multi-Word Input in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing an adventure game in C++ (command line tool format), and I can't figure whether to use a char or string variable for a multi-word input. My code looks something like this:

```
if(directionOne=="go to lake"){cout<<"You are at the lake."}
```

directionOne is the variable that I want to know about. When I use char or string, it just closes the program after I finish.

Comment: What do you mean by "closes the program after I finish"? How do you run it, what operating system, do you click it's icon to run it?

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as `std::string`:

```
std::string directionOne;
```